# Why is Drupal not sending email from Webform?

Tags: webforms

I have entered my email in webform > Emails tab. After I submit the form, I do not get any email. I am just stuck. I submitted the form many times and I got no emails.

Any advise?

Webform: 7.x-4.16

PHP     5.4.45

Drupal: 7.56

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

**Update:**

From name and from email are blank. Still same issue.

Password reset does not send any email.

I also checked with hosting provider. They told me everything works on their end.

Check the recent log. After I submit a form, I do not see anything there regarding the submission.

---

**Update**

Installed the https://www.drupal.org/project/mail_logger  module.

Installed https://www.drupal.org/project/maillog module but not sure how to use it yet.

1. mysite.com/user. Requested for a new password.
2. Went to recent log. I saw it in the log.
3. Went to outgoing mail log. I saw it in the queue.
4. Checked the gmail. Got no email.
5. Gone thru modules. Did not see any email related module.
6. Submitted a webform.
7. Recent log > does not show it.
8. Outgoing mail > shows it.
9. Nothing is going to email including spam.
10. https://www.drupal.org/project/reroute_email Using this module, nothing was rerouted after submitting a webform.
11. This is not a new installation. This happened after migration. Below are the steps taken to migrate. I dont have the problem in source. I have email issue in target.

1) On the source server, upload the backup and migrate module
2) On the source server, take a backup of the database using the B&M module
3) Copy all the site files - Drupal core, modules, themes, and your files folder, and migrate them to the target server in the exact same folder structure as the source server.
(make sure source sites/default folder is write only access)
4) After you have migrated all the files to the target server, delete settings.php, and make a copy default.settings.php called settings.php
5) Install Drupal as a new installation on the target server
6) Enable the backup and migrate module on the target server
7) Use the B&M module to import the database backup you took in step 2

---

**Update**

## Enabled SMTP

## Configured as follows. Not sure if it was a correct config.

Turn this module on or off : On

Turn on delivery of emails : on

Send mail by queue. checked.

Retry sending mail on error. checked.

SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com

Backup SMTP: blank

SMTP port : 465

Use encrypted protocol : no

SMTP Authentication: user name field: my gmail user name

Password: gmail password

E-mail options

E-mail from address: entered workspace email with different domain

email from name: test

SMTP client settings: blank
Send test e-mail: info@domainexample.com

## Once save the configuration, I get this:

```
SMTP.module is active.
The configuration options have been saved.
A test e-mail has been sent to info@domainexample.com. You may want to check the logs for any error messages.
SMTP.module is active.
```

## Checked the email

info@domainexample.com. No email received.

## Recent log shows

"smtp   01/16/2018 - 13:55  Queue sending mail to: info@domainexample.com   admin"

## Submitted request password and a webform.

Got no email.

## recent log:

smtp    01/16/2018 - 14:05  Queue sending mail to: info@domainexample.com   Anonymous (not verified)
smtp    01/16/2018 - 14:03  Password reset instructions mailed to admin at info...  Anonymous (not verified)

## Message from hosting provider:

```
"
loaded php mail script and sent test email to info@domainexample.com. 

serevers are working correctly. "
```

Still no luck.

Comment: Are other emails going out fine? Can you check with password reset form to confirm?

Comment: D 7.56.  I get no email when I try to reset password. I just dont know where to start.

Comment: use mail function in a php file to see if the sever can send email https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp and check with your hosting provider

Comment: I created a page > php filtered in body field > pasted the code from the link > Save. Every time I refresh the page, I get email.

Comment: did you check the drupal dblog ? is this a new installation ? if not i would suggest try to disable as many modules as possible especially related to email ... are you sure your emails dont go in spam ? always check with password reminder and look in spam ... install https://www.drupal.org/project/maillog and maybe some related modules linked from there they might give an indication of what is going on.

Comment: I updated above. if I have more update, ,I will let you know.

Comment: Sending email with PHP can be finicky depending on the server. Try installing the SMTP module to handle sending emails. If you have a Gmail account, you can use its credentials to send up to 100 a day (or sign up for a free Sendgrid account, but it can take longer). Then put in your SMTP credentials and try again.

Comment: @learn4ever I have always had luck with the [SMTP](https://drupal.org/project/smtp) module. Can you try setting it up to check if the emails are being sent?

Comment: I updated above. Still trying to fix it.

Comment: I wiped everything out including database and all files. I installed drupal 7.56 fresh install in cpanel shared hosting server. First thing I tried to reset the password of admin. I get no email.